# Multi including files in JADE

Tags: html, pug

What I have now in my index.jade file:

```
html
  include head
body
  include header
  include main
  include aside
  // a bunch of other includes
  include footer
```

What I prefer to receive

```
html
  include head.jade
body
  +multiinclude('header','main','aside','footer')
```

But when I'm trying to pass an argument in mixin to include directive it doesn't work:

```
mixin multiinclude(...includes)
  each i in includes
    include= i
```

It just add `<include>header</include>` tags

Answer (score 0):

You are passing strings into you `multiinclude` mixin.

You are also trying to loop over your inputs, but they are not in an array format.

Maybe you should include a `body.jade` file, and in the the `body.jade` include the different pieces to the body?